# Cannot install mongodb

Tags: mongodb, macos

I am trying to install mongodb. I am doing the folllowing command

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

I am getting the following output

```
==> Tapping mongodb/brew
Cloning into '/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/mongodb/homebrew-brew'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 49, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (49/49), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (48/48), done.
remote: Total 552 (delta 15), reused 6 (delta 1), pack-reused 503
Receiving objects: 100% (552/552), 118.75 KiB | 315.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (253/253), done.
Error: Invalid formula: /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/mongodb/homebrew-brew/Formula/mongocli.rb
formulae require at least a URL
Error: Cannot tap mongodb/brew: invalid syntax in tap!
```

I searched on various forums and all but could not find any solution.

PS: I am using m1 mac.

Comment: Is the solution below working for you ?

Answer (score -1):

Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66381265/does-the-mongocli-support-a-formula-url-for-apple-m1-chips). Worked for me! You may want to create a duplicate of your terminal for this ;).

You can then proceed to the rest of the installation with a regular Terminal (i.e not under Rosetta)